# Quando é obrigatório o uso de ponto e virgula Javascript

Tags: javascript

Queria saber quando é obrigatório o uso de ponto e virgula no Javascript.

Comment: Uma é mais aberta a opiniões, na outra há o caráter obrigatório.

Answer (score 5):

Ainda o uso do ponto e vírgula é obrigatório ao usar o laço `for` e quando a linha que seguir começar com qualquer um desses você deve terminar o comando com ponto e vírgula:  `([+-/*` [[fonte](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)]

Na maioria dos casos, ele também deverá ser usado quando for usar mais de uma instrução em uma mesma linha. Há a exceção de várias instruções dentro de uma expressão, nesse caso vírgulas podem fazer o papel do ponto e vírgula:

```
if (condição) faça_isso(), e_também_isso()
```

Comment: Também se você quiser ter duas expressões na mesma linha. E para separar os parâmetros do comando `for`.

Comment: A boa prática é usar sempre.

Comment: Cada um segue o próprio estilo: já vi projetos no GitHub que preferem não usar. Não vou deixar de colaborar mas também não vou chegar nele e impor o meu estilo: só saber as implicações de usar-lo.

Comment: É, mas o jslint, do Douglas Crockford, é o padrão amplamente aceito de "bom Javascript" e ele cobra ponto-e-vírgula. O referido autor mostra situações onde a falta do ; deixa o código ambíguo.

Comment: Não acho que isso seja como "gramático contra linguista" porque o Crockford não seria um gramático. Ele é só radical (e por isso mesmo não dá pra concordar com tudo o que ele diz).

Comment: Tá, removi meu comentário pois minha comparação foi muito radical: gramáticos nem se comparam a ele.